# MVC Return Content vs Return View

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc

How can I encapsulate the following code and incorporate it into my view?

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string restURL = "http://loripsum.net/api/3/medium/";
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = client.DownloadString(restURL);
            return Content(data, "application/json");
        }

    }
```

As you can see, I'm not accessing my view page at all, and I'm not sure how to insert this code into the view I have. Can I turn this into a function and then call it with return View(foo)?

Thanks! Sorry, It's been years since I've used mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I get your meaning, you're wanting to embed "data" within a view you already have - so depending on what "data" is, you should create a ViewModel (just a standard C# class) with a property in it - lets assume data is a string since you're retrieving it as a string.  Set the property's value to data, then return your View from this method, and pass in your new ViewModel.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string LoremContent { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string restURL = "http://loripsum.net/api/3/medium/";
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = client.DownloadString(restURL);
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel() { LoremContent = data };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can refer to @Model.LoremContent - if it's HTML you can just use @Html.Raw(Model.LoremContent) to render it.   Be sure to validate the content if you're going to do this, otherwise you're making yourself vulnerable to a script attack.

Comment: Thank you so much Russell, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Russell, might I ask - when you refer to validating, are you referring to binding my model? Here is the final product that you helped me with. Thanks again https://dotnetfiddle.net/FVBCGq

Comment: Well if you think about it, if you're rendering content that comes from a third party site, and you're not checking it at all - what if someone hacks that site or service such that it returns a malicious script?  You'd be helping propagate that script directly by embedding it without doing any checking on it's content.

Comment: Yes, that totally makes sense. I'll have to look into how to validate 3rd party content. You've already done more than enough, but if you have an referrals I could use to learn more about this, it would be appreciated. In any case, thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Check out http://owasp.org - the Top10 project is a good place to start.  It's not often you'd want to just render content from a third party site as html, so I guess this might be academic for your live end-result project.